How to get ajv.compile() error line and column information
When using ajv.compile(), how do you get line and column information about schema compile errors?
NOTE: This relates to compile errors. I'm not running validate() and I'm not looking for location information when validating a specific JSON object against the schema. I'm validating the schema itself.
validateSchema.ts
const { data: schema, pointers } = jsonSourceMap.parse(
    fsExtra.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../my.schema.json`).toString()
);
const ajv = new Ajv({
    strict: true,
    allErrors: true,
    verbose: true
});

ajv.compile(schema, true);


my.schema.json
{
    "title": "JSON schema for names",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "deprecated": true,
            "deprecationMessage": "Deprecated. Use `firstName` and `lastName` instead.",
            "description": "Your full name"
        }
    }
}

In the example above, we're using strict mode and there's a nonstandard key called `"deprecationMessage". It will throw an error with a message like this:
Error: strict mode: unknown keyword: "deprecationMessage"

I would like to see an error message more like this:
Error: strict mode: unknown keyword: "deprecationMessage" at my.schema.json 9:14-9:32


You can use better-ajv-errors package to get the desired result
https://github.com/atlassian/better-ajv-errors
const betterAjvErrors = require('better-ajv-errors').default;

const { data: schema, pointers } = jsonSourceMap.parse(
    fsExtra.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../my.schema.json`).toString()
);
const ajv = new Ajv({
    strict: true,
    allErrors: true,
    verbose: true
});

let validate = ajv.compile(schema, true);

const valid = validate(data);

if (!valid) {
  const output = betterAjvErrors(schema, data, validate.errors);
  console.log(output);
};



just to follow up on this a bit more.. the betterAjvErrors will only output a result after a validation has been performed.  Any Ajv specific errors when using strict: true will be evaluated prior to evaluation and an error output will be sent before betterAjvErrors can be executed.

Thanks, but I want the compile errors to have location information, whereas this appears to be a tool for validating data. I just ran your example, and my compile error still shows    Error: strict mode: unknown keyword: "deprecationMessage" without location information.

I realize my comment isn't the most clear, but I was past the edit window. My code example above is the full body of my function. I'll never be running ajv.validate() because that's not my goal. I am validating that my schema file itself is valid. And if there are errors with the schema (surfaced when calling ajv.compile(), I want to know the line and column locations for those errors in the schema file.

that's a better question for the library author. I don't think the error output is setup for that in this library. It's not really a compile error in the JS sense, it's an internal validation of a schema in the library.
